# AttachmentPart : how to get the name?

Tags: java, soap

I have code that calls a soap web service that has an attachment (or multiple attachments) that is a zip file (o multiple ones). I only want some of those zip files, the ones that start with "WCT_".

Is it possible at all, given an AttachmentPart variable, to get the name of the file?

```
Iterator<?> i = soapResponse.getAttachments();
Object obj = null;
while (i.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("file found");
    AttachmentPart att = (AttachmentPart) i.next();
```

I tried att.getContent().toString() but didn't print the name.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
Iterator<?> i = soapResponse.getAttachments();
Object obj = null;
while (i.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("file found");
    AttachmentPart att = (AttachmentPart) i.next();
    String fileName = att.getDataHandler().getName();
}
```

Comment: @mchl45 print the result of the method getAllMimeHeaders() of AttachmentPart

Comment: I tried System.out.println(att.getAllMimeHeaders()); and it didn't print the name . It printed some weird characters

Comment: Try with att.getAllMimeHeaders().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);

Comment: My project compliance and JRE are 1.7 . When I type that it suggests me to change the compliance to 1.8 (which I can't because some of my other code wouldn't work). Do you know how to modify your line to fulfill 1.7?

Comment: `Iterator iterator = att.getAllMimeHeaders();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}`

Comment: unfortunately still not printing the name. For each attachment, it prints javax.xml.soap.MimeHeader@3c09711b
javax.xml.soap.MimeHeader@5cc7c2a6
javax.xml.soap.MimeHeader@b97c004

Comment: change the content of while with    
`MimeHeader mimeHeader = (MimeHeader)iterator.next();
    System.out.println(mimeHeader.getName()  + " : " + mimeHeader.getValue());`

Comment: for each file it prints Content-Type : text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding : binary
Content-ID : <421a95d4-c9f0-471d-a7d7-d99091458d58>

Comment: Seems that the client don't declare filename.